# externalize properties in grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to just externalize some custom properties in grails.

I cannot find a clear way on how to externalize some string properties and use them in my code.
Can any one please help me out.

Comment: Did you read http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the location of the external configuration file in the config.groovy.

For example like this:

```
if (!grails.config.locations || !(grails.config.locations instanceof List)) {
    grails.config.locations = []
}

// Internal Jetty: config-files are locates inside the /web-app/WEB-INF directory
if( GrailsUtil.isDevelopmentEnv() ) {
    def dir = System.properties["base.dir"]
    def f1 = "${dir}" + File.separator + "web-app" + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "${appName}-config.groovy"
    grails.config.locations << "file:${f1}"
}

// TIER Tomcat: config-files are locates inside Tomcat's conf-directory
else if( System.properties["catalina.home"] ) {
    def dir = System.properties["catalina.home"]
    def f1 = "${dir}" + File.separator + "conf" + File.separator + "${appName}-config.groovy"
    grails.config.locations << "file:${f1}"
}

// JBOSS, Glassfish etc
else {
    //
}

// Further choices: command line argument (-D{$appName}.config.location=xxx)
if( System.properties["${appName}.config.location"] ) {
  grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
}
```

So on local development the config file is locate under the WEB-INF directory.
While going life you have various choices of where to put your configuration file.
You can adapt, if needed, the code to works for config.properties in the same way.